# I want to get rid of the line

Tags: polygon, line

So I used a set of coordinates into QGIS, so whenever I input another set of coordinates into the same Excel and exported it to QGIS I always get this result when converting points to polygons using points2one plugin. A line that runs from the endpoint of the first set of coordinates to the startpoint of another sets of coordinates. Is there a way I can get rid of this line?

Image 1: Points from exported coordinates
[image]

Image 2: Creating a polygon using those sets of coordinates
[image]

Note: The line shown on image 2 is the one that I want to get rid of.

Image 3: Set of coordinates
[image]

So the coordinates that I highlighted are the one that are connecting to each other. Is there a way I can get rid of this line? Or how do I work around with these coordinates to fix it?

Comment: You have a polygon geometry with an interior ring ("hole"). The proper construction of these objects involves "picking up the pen" when moving from exterior to interior. You should probably [Edit] the Question to provide more details on how you constructed the geometry.

Comment: Hi Vince, Thank you for the feedback. There's suppose to be a hole in the polygon because its a Domestic Fishing Zone, so there are islands within. So I calculated these coordinates using the Buffer tool in QGIS and a baseline.

Comment: I hope this provides more detail, I just want to know if there's any other way to fix it please?

Comment: Editing the Question is required to provide more detail. Commenting on your own post just adds to the clutter. I'm not the person who will answer. You need to go into even more detail about how you generated that corrupt geometry, so a QGIS user can help you.